# Why the newline after the %d is eaten but not the %c in the fmt.Scanf?

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    var num int
    n, err := fmt.Scanf("%d", &num)
    fmt.Println(n, num)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    var r1 rune
    n, err = fmt.Scanf("%c", &r1)
    fmt.Println(n, r1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    var r2 rune
    n, err = fmt.Scanf("%c", &r2)
    fmt.Println(n, r2)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

input(Keyboard keys) is:
`1 enter a enter`

output is:

`1 1`
`1 97`
`1 10`

Why the value of `r2` is `\n` but the the value of `r1` is `a`? 

In the comment of the `fmt.Scanf`:

> Newlines in the input must match newlines in the format. The one exception: the verb %c always scans the next rune in the input, even if it is a space (or tab etc.) or newline.

It seems that the newline after the `%d` is eaten but the newline after `%c` is not. Is the newline after the `%d` miss matching?

Another example: https://play.studygolang.com/p/lRgxrUqyBTI , I try to use a buffer to substitute for the stdin, but the output is different from using the stdin.

go version is `go version go1.17.1 windows/amd64`

Comment: You don't match the newlines in the format, though, even though you quoted the doc where you said you had to.

Comment: `n, err = fmt.Scanf("%c", &r1)`. I don't know why the `%c` don't match the newline after the `%d`, in other words, the first `enter` is eaten.

Comment: aah, gotcha.  thanks.  Terminal input makes questions like this difficult to reproduce.  I was unable to get the behavior you describe for buffered input : https://play.golang.org/p/usHn6UhiKTU  - I get `1 1 1 10 1 97` which is what we'd expect.  Think you can make that reproduce your problem in a playground like that?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The output is `1 1 1 97 1 10`  when I run the code in the GoLand IDE and typing `1 enter a enter` directly, but the output is `1 1 1 10 1 97` (same as you) when I run the code with `go run main.go` command and typing `1 enter a enter`.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1091980/why-are-windows-line-breaks-larger-than-unix-line-breaks I wonder if windows' nonstandard  end of line pattern could be throwing it off.

Comment: I looked over the documentation very carefully, and to be honest I dont even really see where its documented that newline ends Scanf. So I think this is a good question, as the function in question appears to be under documented. If you dont get a good answer remind me, and I will bounty this

Comment: Thanks! I still have no clue. Maybe I misunderstand the stdin and raise a "childish" question  : ) ? From the source code, `fmt.Scanf(format string, a ...interface{})`  calls `Fscanf(os.Stdin, format, a...)` directly, but when I use a buffered input to replace the os.stdin, the output is different. (See https://play.studygolang.com/p/lRgxrUqyBTI).

Answer (score 0):

a newline is a single character that is valid input for a rune but not for a int, so when you capture a rune the new line is read and stored while that is not done for other types.

if  you don't capture the new line while reading to a rune you will get the error "unexpected newlnie" if yuo try to read from stdin again.

i suggest you do the following to read runes so you always capture the newline and don't get unexpected results

```golang
var r1, r2 rune
n, err = fmt.Scanf("%c%c", &r1, &r2)
fmt.Println(n, r1, r2)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
```